# Replace li text using jquery without changing other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace the content of li and  tags.

Tried below code.

```
<html>
   <head>Sample</head>
   <body>
    <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname">Test <span class="count">5</span>      </a>

    <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname1">Test1 <span class="count">10</span> </a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Mixed assessment guidelines</a></li>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Plagiarism </a></li>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Download </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Qualification update</a></li>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Exam guide update</a></li>
      <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Guide </a></li>
    </ul>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function($) {
        var value = 0.4;
        $("body").find('li').each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).text() != '') {
              var str = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
              var newstring =  str + str.substring(0, str.length  * value);
              $(this).text(newstring);
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to replace the text of every li inside the body. so used above jquery for it. But it is not working.

Example :

```
<li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Plagiarism </a></li>
```

Should replace as

```
<li><a href="#" rel="noopener">PlagiarismPlag </a></li>
```

First four characters of each li text. That is **Plag** in the above example

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: need to replace this two line of code.  var str = $(this).text();
                    var newstring =  str + str.substring(0, 4);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('li>a').each(function(index, element) {
    var b = "Plag"
    var data = $(this).text(); // it will give 1,2,3 
    var position = (data.substring(0, 4))
    var output = [data, position].join('');
    $(this).empty().append("<a/>" + output);
    return index < 3;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname">Test <span class="count">5</span> </a>

<a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname1">Test1 <span class="count">10</span> </a>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Mixed assessment guidelines</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Plagiarism </a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Download </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Qualification update</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Exam guide update</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Guide </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hi @Aishwarya, I need to add on the fly for all li items

Comment: No, var b = "Plag", you are appending this text, But I need to fetch first 4 characters of the word

Comment: hi @Aishwarya, why u are adding var b = "Plag", this will replace for all li, I need to get each li text and add first 4 characters at the end each of li with the original text

Comment: Right now its adding Plug for all li

Comment: I am checking 2mns.

Comment: yes somewhat, but I have many li inside page, making problem in other part

Comment: try to used span inside li

Answer (score 1):

Rather than cloning, try replacing the `li > a`'s text directly. No need to test if the string is empty first, because if it is empty, the existing text (empty string) won't change:

```js
var value = 0.4;
$("body").find('li > a').each(function(index) {
  const text = $(this).text();
  const newText = text + text.slice(0, Math.floor(text.length * value));
  $(this).text(newText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname">Test <span class="count">5</span> </a>

<a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname1">Test1 <span class="count">10</span> </a>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Mixed assessment guidelines</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Plagiarism </a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Download </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Qualification update</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Exam guide update</a></li>
  <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Guide </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Case You can use like this. Try This

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $("body").find('li').each(function (e) {
        if ($(this).text() != '') {

            var str = $(this).text();
            var newstring =  str.substring(0, 4) + str;
            $(this).children('a')[0].innerHTML = newstring;
        }
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname">Test <span class="count">5</span>      </a>

    <a href="#"><input type="checkbox" class="layer-input-filter" name="testname1">Test1 <span class="count">10</span> </a>
            
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Mixed assessment guidelines</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen </a></li>
        <li><a id="btnChange" href="#" rel="noopener">Plagiarism </a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Download </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Qualification update</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Specimen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="noopener">Exam guide update</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Guide </a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: hi @Darshana, this will replace a tag also

Comment: I fixed that. Check out @jafarpinjar

Answer (score -1):

I hope to help you with this code :

```
    var str = $(this).find('a').text();
    var newStr = str + str.substr(0, 4);
    $(this).find('a').text(newStr)
```

sample code : https://jsfiddle.net/3w4j8q16/1/

Comment: I am asking for li text ,

Comment: @jafarpinjar yes, have you seen the sample code what I wrote? I changed li text.